# Cython fails to recognize overloaded constructor

Tags: python, c++, constructor, cython

I'm trying to compile the [cyrand](http://github.com/andrewcron/cyrand/) project using cython, but am running into a bizarre compile error when testing overloaded constructors.  See this [gist](http://gist.github.com/lzamparo/39a951106dafe9aaabf0) for the files in question.

From the gist, I can compile and run example.pyx just fine, which uses the default constructor:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cimport cython

include "random.pyx"

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def example(n):

    cdef int N = n

    cdef rng r
    cdef rng_sampler[double] * rng_p = new rng_sampler[double](r)
    cdef rng_sampler[double] rng = deref(rng_p)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] result = np.empty(N, dtype=np.double)

    for i in range(N):
        result[i] = rng.normal(0.0, 2.0)
    print result
    return result
```

^ this works and runs fine.  An example run produces the following output:

`$ python test_example.py
[ 0.47237842 3.153744849 3.6854932057 ]`

Yet when I try to compile and run the test which used a constructor that takes an unsigned long as argument:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cimport cython

include "random.pyx"

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def example_seed(n, seed):

    cdef int N = n
    cdef unsigned long Seed = seed

    cdef rng r
    cdef rng_sampler[double] * rng_p = new rng_sampler[double](Seed)
    cdef rng_sampler[double] rng = deref(rng_p)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] result = np.empty(N, dtype=np.double)

    for i in range(N):
        result[i] = rng.normal(0.0, 2.0)
    print result
    return result
```

I get the following cython compiler error:

```
    Error compiling Cython file:
    ----------------------------------------------------------- 
    ...    
       cdef int N = n    
       cdef unsigned long Seed = seed

       cdef rng_sampler[double] * rng_p = new rng_sampler[double](Seed)
    ---------------------------------------------------------- 
    example/example_seed.pyx:15:67 Cannot assign type 'unsigned long' to 'mt19937'
```

I interpret this message, along with the fact that example.pyx compiles and produces a working `example.so` file, that cython cannot find (or manage) the rng_sampler constructor that takes an unsigned long as input.  I've not used cython before, and my cpp is middling at best.  Can anyone shed light on how to fix this simple problem?

python: 2.7.10 (Anaconda 2.0.1)
cython: 0.22.1

Comment: It appears to work with Cython 0.21.1 (I've only done the compilation with Cython though, not the compilation with C++). I suspect this is a bug that's appeared in Cython 0.22.1, and might be worth reporting.

Comment: @DavidW: could you post your other relevant environment configurations?  After downgrading to Cython 0.21.1 still encounter the same error.

Comment: @DavidW: Thanks for the data point.  After downgrading to 0.21.1 I got the same result.  Then I tried on a different machine, it worked.  I tried upgrading to 0.22.1, it worked.  Then on the original machine, I installed a different version of boost, and it worked.  So, this ended up being a problem with how I had installed boost :/

Comment: Not a clue what's going on but glad you got it working! I'll assume you no longer need any other details unless you say otherwise.

Comment: Not sure exactly what lead to this error message either... Some linking error, or maybe to do with how Debian (and Scinet) package boost.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error, it was to do with how boost is installed.  I had installed boost via apt-get.  After downloading/untarring and changing the pointers to boost in setup.py, it works.